# Как выбрать записи из связанных таблиц ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, mapping

Две сущности, связаны отношением ManyToMany:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR)
    protected Long id;

    protected String code;

    @ManyToMany(CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "CATEGORY_ITEM",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID")
    )
    protected Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       Category category = (Category) o;
      return Objects.equals(code, category.code);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(code);
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR)
    protected Long id;

    protected String code;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    protected Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       Item item = (Item) o;
      return Objects.equals(code, item.code);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(code);
    }
}
```

Я хочу найти список всех объектов `items` для конкретной категории.

Так мне нужны объекты `Item`, а эта информация есть только в таблице `Category`, то написал такой запрос в `CategoryRepository`:

```
    @Query("select i from Category c join с.items i where c.code = :code")
    List<Item> findItemsWithCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

В результате получаю пустой список.

Хотя если прочитать конкретный объект

```
Category сategory = CategoryRepository.getId(1);
```

из из него извлечь список, то данные там есть

```
assertEquals(сategory.getItems().size(), 2);
```

Пробовал такой вариант, но все равно получаю пустой список:

```
@Query("select c.items from Category с i where c.code = :code")
    List<Item> findItemsWithCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

Пробовал написать запрос на стороне ItemRepository и тоже пустой список:

```
 @Query("select i from Item i join i.categories c where c.code = :code")
    List<Item> findItemsWithCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

Как мне получить эти данные?

Comment: Какая ошибка возникает?

Comment: Нет ни какой ошибки. Получаю пустой список. Просто не пойму почему этот запрос не работает. 
"Я хочу найти список всех объектов items для конкретной категории."

Comment: Запрос не работает потому, что он неверный. Покажите DDL для таблиц.

Comment: @Roman C, Извиняюсь, я исправил поле в сущностях. В спешке не то поле удалил

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```java
@Query("select i from Category c join c.items i where c.code = :code")
List<Item> findItemsWithCode(@Param("code") String code);
```